# Use index as an extra id in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Let's suppose that I execute the following query in C#

```
    var query = from b in db.SchoolTestsPerModulePerStudent
                where b.Student.Equals(2)
                select b;
```

Ok, I get as results all the records of my model SchoolTestsPerModulePerStudent. 
However, Is it possible, to add a new Id when executing the query?

That means that if my model has 4 fields, StudentID, ModuleID, DateTest and GradeTest, to get the following

```
1, 2, 3, 1 January 2013, 76

2, 2, 3, 5 January 2013, 79

3, 2, 4, 1 January 2013, 73

4, 2, 4, 7 January 2013, 71
```

How I can do that?

Comment: You need it as a string for example or you need it to perform a query on database?

Comment: @GrantWinney i believe the first column is the one he wants to add... the new id

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks a lot for your comments. Basicaly, I want to create a chart using javascript (graphael chart). But that specific library, does not accept dates as data points. So what I will do is instead of passing (Date,Grade) as a point, to pass (id,Grade)...

Comment: And yes, the first column is the id...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload of `Select` that gives you the index:

```
var resultsWithId = query.Select((q, i) => new { Id = i, Student = q });
```

This will put the results in an anonymous object.

EDIT: As Nico mentions below, this might be hard to use as a ViewModel. If you want to use it as that, create a new defined class that can hold the info:

```
public class MyClass
{
    int Id;
    int StudentId;
    //etc
}

var resultsWithId = query.Select((q, i) => new MyClass { 
                                                 Id = i + 1, //one based index 
                                                 StudentId = q.StudentId 
                                                 //etc
                                               });
```

Comment: +1 I had no idea! Thanks for sharing.. The only downfall with this method is it will make it hard to use as the ViewModel (with anonymous types), but the concept is there and quite clean..

Comment: hmmm... this seems really nice. I will try to use that. +1 for your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Id = i + 1`? Looks like OP wants a one based index.

Comment: @ekad you're right, if he wants a one-based index then it should be `i + 1`. Thanks!

Comment: Also selected as best answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you convert your query to a list using `.ToList()`, you can use `query.IndexOf()` to get the 0 based index of the item in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to just add an extra property to your class to be returned to your model? If you need a concrete class structure for your View you will need to create a new model with this new property as anonymous types wont be useful in a View Model.

```
public class MyNewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long StudentID { get; set; }
    public long ModuleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTest { get; set; }
    public int GradeTest { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will need to convert your orignal query to a `List()` and select your new model type setting the value.

```
var query = (from b in db.SchoolTestsPerModulePerStudent
            where b.StudentID.Equals(2)
            select b).ToList();

var newResults = query.Select(x => new MyNewModel
{
    DateTest = x.TestDate,
    StudentID = x.StudentID,
    GradeTest = x.TestResult,
    ModuleID = x.ModuleID,
    Id = query.IndexOf(x)
});
```

It also may be quicker to just do this in your view by passing the query as a List to your view and using the `IndexOf()` method while enumerating the set.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use Select().

```
source.Select(x=>new Model{newid=something,p1=x.p1,p2=x.p2....})
```

or

```
source.Select(x=>new{newid=something,x.p1,x.p2.....})
```

or if you want newid is index,you can use

```
source.Select((x,index)=>new{newid=index,x.p1,x.p2.....})
```

you can do more linq after select function

Comment: Thanks a lot chenZ. +1 from me